# A toast message is displaying on versions lower than Marshmallow

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-intent

I have an Android app in production. Everything is working correctly but on Versions lower than Android M, in each activity i'm getting a toast message "not greater than M"? Is there anyone who can help me fixing this? I'm attaching a screenshot[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WP3R8.jpg)

Comment: There's some code in your app that is displaying those toasts. Could also be from a library you are using.

Comment: Thank You So much, I have solved the issue, there's a code, I found that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A toast would **never** show up in an Android app except it is present somewhere in the codebase. The most likely cause of this problem is that there is a part of your codebase where you are creating a Toast.

Scan through the affected class and remove the line of code that displays the Toast. If your class is lengthy, you can just hit [*CTRL + F*] or [*CMD + F*] and search for "not greater than M" since those are the exact words your Toast is displaying.